# Why in Rails 3, <%= note.html_safe %> and <%= h note.html_safe %> give the same result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, xss, html-escape, html-safe

It feels like `html_safe` adds an abstraction to the String class that requires understanding of what is going on, for example,

```
<%= '1 <b>2</b>' %>      # gives 1 &lt;b&gt;2&lt;/b&gt; in the HTML source code

<%= h '1 <b>2</b>' %>    # exactly the same as above

<%= '1 <b>2</b>'.html_safe %>      #  1 <b>2</b>  in HTML source code

<%= h '1 <b>2</b>'.html_safe %>    #  exactly the same as above

<%= h (h '1 <b>2</b>') %>  #  1 &lt;b&gt;2&lt;/b&gt;   wont' escape twice
```

For line 4, if we are saying, ok, we trust the string -- it is safe, but why can't we escape it?  It seems that to escape it by `h`, the string has to be unsafe.

So on line 1, if the string is not escaped by `h`, it will be automatically escaped.  On line 5, `h` cannot escape the string twice -- in other words, after `<` is changed to `&lt;`, it can't escape it one more time to `&amp;lt;`.

So what's happening?  At first, I thought `html_safe` is just tagging a flag to the string, saying it is safe.  So then, why does `h` not escape it?  It seems that `h` and `html_escape` actually co-operate on using the flag:

1) If a string is html_safe, then `h` will not escape it

2) If a string is not html_safe, then when the string is added to the output buffer, it will be automatically escaped by `h`.

3) If `h` already escaped a string, it is marked `html_safe`, and therefore, escaping it one more time by `h` won't take any effect. (as on Line 5, and that behavior is the same even in Rails 2.3.10, but on Rails 2.3.5 `h` can actually escape it twice... so in Rails 2.3.5, `h` is a simple escape method, but some where along the line to 2.3.10, `h` became not as simple.  But 2.3.10 won't auto escape a string, but for some reason, the method `html_safe` already exists for 2.3.10 (for what purpose?))

Is that how it works exactly?  I think nowadays, sometimes we don't get what we want in the output and we immediately add `html_safe` to our variable, which can be quite dangerous, because it can introduce XSS attack that way, so understanding how it exactly works can be quite important.  The above is only a guess of how it exactly work.  Could it be actually a different mechanism and is there any doc that supports it?

Answer (score 6):

As you can see, calling html_safe on a string turns it into an html safe SafeBuffer

http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89978f10afbad3f856e2959a811bed1982715408/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb#L87

Any operations on a SafeBuffer that could affect the string safety will be passed through h()

h uses this flag to avoid double escaping

http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89978f10afbad3f856e2959a811bed1982715408/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb#L18

The behavior did change and I think you are mostly correct about how it works.  In general you should not call html_safe unless you're sure that it is already sanitized.  Like anything, you have to be careful while using it

Comment: interesting... it uses a new class SafeBuffer as the "flag"...  so `"foobar".html_safe` will actually create and return a new instance of SafeBuffer with the content of the original string...

Answer (score 0):

in rails 3, all output is using the `h` helper by default

see http://origami.co.uk/blog/2010/02/rails-3-html-escaping

if you don't want escaping you can use `raw`