# link_to_function not working properly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I upgraded rails application from rails `2.3.14` to rails `3.2.6`. link_to_function is not generating right html.

following helper method . . .

```
link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
```

is generating ...

```
<a href="#" onclick="add_fields(this, &amp;quot;quick_facts&amp;quot;, &amp;quot;&amp;lt;div class=\'quick_fact\'&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;div class=\'grid_4 prefix_1\'&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;label for=\&amp;quot;organization_quick_facts_attributes_new_quick_facts_quick_fact\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;QuickFact&amp;lt;\/label&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;br&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;select class=\&amp;quot;quick_fact_select\&amp;quot; id=\&amp;quot;organization_quick_facts_attributes_new_quick_facts_quick_fact\&amp;quot; name=\&amp;quot;organization[quick_facts_attributes][new_quick_facts][quick_fact]\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;option value=\&amp;quot;\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;\/option&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;option value=\&amp;quot;Hours\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Hours&amp;lt;\/option&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;option value=\&amp;quot;Serving\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Serving&amp;lt;\/option&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;option value=\&amp;quot;Insurance Accepted\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Insurance Accepted&amp;lt;\/option&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;option value=\&amp;quot;Features\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Features&amp;lt;\/option&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;option value=\&amp;quot;Services Provided\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Services Provided&amp;lt;\/option&amp;gt;&amp;lt;\/select&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;br&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;\/div&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;div class=\'clear\'&amp;gt;&amp;lt;\/div&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;div class=\'grid_4 prefix_1\'&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;label for=\&amp;quot;organization_quick_facts_attributes_new_quick_facts_content\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Content&amp;lt;\/label&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;br&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;input id=\&amp;quot;organization_quick_facts_attributes_new_quick_facts_content\&amp;quot; maxlength=\&amp;quot;200\&amp;quot; name=\&amp;quot;organization[quick_facts_attributes][new_quick_facts][content]\&amp;quot; size=\&amp;quot;200\&amp;quot; type=\&amp;quot;text\&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;\n    &amp;lt;br&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;\/div&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;div class=\'clear\'&amp;gt;&amp;lt;\/div&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;div class=\'grid_2 prefix_1 exempt\'&amp;gt;\n    &amp;amp;nbsp;\n    &amp;lt;a href=\&amp;quot;#\&amp;quot; class=\&amp;quot;remove_temp_qf\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;remove&amp;lt;\/a&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;\/div&amp;gt;\n&amp;lt;\/div&amp;gt;\n&amp;quot;); return false;">Add Another QuickFact</a>
```

when this html is rendered, onclick function is not being called and here is the error.

```
syntax error

add_fields(this, &quot;quick_facts&quot;, &quot;&lt;div class=\'quick_fact\'&gt;...

quick_facts# (line 1, col 17)
```

any idea to solve this??

Comment: your call to the `h()` method is escaping the quote fields. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Be aware that `link_to_function` has been sacrificed to the gods of UJS: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5922. It's deprecated and will be removed in Rails 4. I must admit I was happy to see it go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #h method has changed in Rails 3, and Rails 3 is now automatically escaping "unsafe" strings. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070257/why-in-rails-3-note-html-safe-and-h-note-html-safe-give-the-same) for more info.